# Error of $-i$ factor in light cone indices in conformal field theory in Becker's book

Tags: metric-tensor, string-theory, conventions, conformal-field-theory, wick-rotation

In Becker's book of String theory Ch-$3$ I'm getting an error of factor $-i$ in the definition of lightcone indicies after Wick rotation. The convention of the book is following $\sigma_{\pm}=\tau\pm\sigma$ and the Wick rotation as $\tau\rightarrow-i\tau$. Therefore $\sigma_{\pm}$ should be $$-i\tau\pm\sigma$$ $$=-i(\tau\pm i\sigma)$$ $=-iz$ and $-i\bar{z}$ but Becker claims it should be just $z$ and $\bar{z}$.

I'm missing a very simple thing but don't know what it is? The only thing I think could be used is the fact that in conformal transformation is $z\rightarrow f(z)$ and $\bar{z}\rightarrow \bar{f}(\bar{z})$ but still after using such transformation $(z\rightarrow iz)$ we will get the pair $(z,-\bar{z})$ so there is still a mismatch.